# How do I blur a gradient background?

Tags: java, android, android-layout-editor

Lest say I have a gradient background like this right

Example:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#09203f "
        android:endColor="#537895"/>
</shape>
```

How do i blur it and make it look like this in the background of my layout?

Example:

[image]

Comment: You might wanna use this library : https://github.com/CameraKit/blurkit-android

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it!